# How do I map a complex nested object to a simple object using Automapper?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, automapper, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to consume Event Espresso 4 (EE4) REST API in my Xamarin forms app. The DTO that I receive (as JSON) from EE4 REST API is fairly complicated and I would like to flatten it into my "fairly simple" model that I will be using within the app.

The DTO that I receive from EE4 REST API looks as follows:

```
[
    {
        "ATT_ID": 10686,
        "ATT_full_name": "Four Nights",
        "ATT_fname": "Four",
        "ATT_lname": "Nights",
        "ATT_email": "four.nights@yopmail.com",
        "ATT_phone": "+18001579534565",
        "registrations": [
            {
                "REG_ID": 183,
                "EVT_ID": 10584,
                "ATT_ID": 10686,
                "TXN_ID": 66,
                "TKT_ID": 4,
                "STS_ID": "RAP",
                "REG_date": "2019-02-13T09:30:00",
                "REG_code": "66-4-1-24bf",
                "REG_count": 1,
                "REG_group_size": 1,
                "REG_date_gmt": "2019-02-13T08:30:00",
                "_calculated_fields": {
                    "_protected": []
                },
                "transaction": {
                    "TXN_ID": 66,
                    "STS_ID": "TCM",
                    "payments": [
                        {
                            "PAY_ID": 20,
                            "TXN_ID": 66,
                            "STS_ID": "PAP",
                            "PMD_ID": 11
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "ANS_ID": 112,
                        "ANS_value": "Male",
                        "question": {
                            "QST_ID": 11,
                            "QST_display_text": {
                                "raw": "Gender",
                                "rendered": "<p>Gender</p>\n"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "ANS_ID": 113,
                        "ANS_value": [
                            "Double Occupancy"
                        ],
                        "question": {
                            "QST_ID": 12,
                            "QST_display_text": {
                                "raw": "Room Type",
                                "rendered": "<p>Room Type</p>\n"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "ANS_ID": 114,
                        "ANS_value": "None",
                        "question": {
                            "QST_ID": 13,
                            "QST_display_text": {
                                "raw": "Who would you like to share your room with?",
                                "rendered": "<p>Who would you like to share your room with?</p>\n"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The C# equivalent that I have in my project is [here](https://app.quicktype.io?share=orkTWtuGu7xXewuijYbK).

My simple C# object looks as follows:

```
public class Attendee : RealmObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int RegistrationId { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationCode { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset RegistrationDateGMT { get; set; }
    public long EventId { get; set; }
    public long TicketId { get; set; }
    public long GroupCount { get; set; }
    public long TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string TransactionStatus { get; set; }
    public long PaymentId { get; set; }
    public string PaymentStatus { get; set; }
    public string CheckedIn { get; set; }

    public Attendee()
    {
    }

}
```

I've tried different things like ForMember and ForPath. I have also tried mapping the internal objects to the simple one but I keep getting the following error:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
===================================================
AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration.
Char -> Attendee (Destination member list)
System.Char -> Organizer.Models.Attendees.Attendee (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
Id
FirstName
LastName
FullName
Email
Phone
Type
RegistrationId
RegistrationCode
RegistrationStatus
RegistrationDate
RegistrationDateGMT
EventId
TicketId
GroupCount
TransactionId
TransactionStatus
PaymentId
PaymentStatus
CheckedIn
```

I appreciate any help I could get on the mapping them.

Thanks

EDIT:

In the same project I have to following JSON and C# objects and mapping configuration and although the objects are different, the mappings work perfectly well.

JSON Object from EE4 REST API

```
[
    {
        "EVT_ID": 10584,
        "EVT_name": "Mamboland Milano 2019",
        "status": {
            "raw": "publish",
            "pretty": "Published"
        },
        "EVT_visible_on": "2019-01-26T16:11:04",
        "datetimes": [
            {
                "DTT_ID": 1,
                "DTT_EVT_start": "2019-04-04T12:00:00",
                "DTT_EVT_end": "2019-04-08T04:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My C# Object

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int DateTimeID { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Start { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset End { get; set; }
    public string VLogo { get; set; }
    public string HLogo { get; set; }

    public Event()
    {

    }
}
```

Automapper Mapping configuration for the above:

```
#region Event Mappings

//Inner Class Status
CreateMap<DTOs.Status, Models.Event>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Status, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Pretty))
    .ReverseMap();


//Inner Class Datetime
CreateMap<DTOs.Datetime, Models.Event>()
    .ForMember(d => d.DateTimeID, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
    .ForMember(d => d.Start, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Start))
    .ForMember(d => d.End, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.End))
    .ReverseMap();

//Outer Class
CreateMap<DTOs.Event, Models.Event>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
    .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
    .ForMember(d => d.City, o => o.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.Status, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Status.Pretty))
    .ForMember(d => d.DateTimeID, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Datetimes.ToList().FirstOrDefault().Id))
    .ForMember(d => d.Start, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Datetimes.ToList().FirstOrDefault().Start))
    .ForMember(d => d.End, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Datetimes.ToList().FirstOrDefault().End))
    .ForMember(d => d.VLogo, o => o.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.Ignore())
    .ReverseMap();
#endregion
```

As you can see, I have had to first map the inner classes and then map the outer classes and in doing so, I have been able to generate my c# objects just by mapping.

Comment: But your source object looks nothing like the destination object, so maybe you're better off mapping by hand. There's no auto here, so how could AM help?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu: See my edits above, I have an Event object in the same project where the objects are different and I have been able to map them successfully just by using Automapper configuration. This is the essence of Automapper no??

Comment: Auto is the essence of AM :) The more configuration you have, the less useful it is. And more attractive the manual solution looks. It's true that some of your MapFroms are not needed. So it depends.